# Change the style of the output of a model in QGIS

Tags: qgis, qgis-modeler

I have the output for a model in QGIS, but I want it to have a specific colour ramp. It is one of the default colour ramps offered in the Symbology menu for the Singleband Pseudocolour render type (It is the "Blues" colour ramp). How can I get the model to output the same output it does currently, but with this colour ramp applied to it already. I could do it by hand, but I have to run this program a lot, so I will get many output files and was just wondering if this is possible?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Style one layer manually, right click it and Export - Save As Qgis layer style file.

Apply the style file to the model result with Set layer style:

[image]

Comment: Just replying to say thanks because it did work, I was trying to edit it by right-clicking on the model in the Processing Toolbox and clicking the "Edit Rendering Styles for Output" option, which then allowed me to choose the layer style file separately but it didn't work that way for some reason, but this method does.

Comment: I've just encountered another problem, as the floods I was simulating here had a peak height of 3m, and so did the specific simulated lake from which I pulled the layer style file from. Now, I modified the processing model slightly so I could simulate floods for other DEMs, but the one I am working on has a peak height of more than 3m, so the actual processing model works fine, but it's restricted the colour ramp to a max value of 3, which isn't accurate. How do I change that so that it allows the colour ramp to be accurately applied to any lake with any max and min elevation?